# Is there any webhook available to know if google Filt new data are available for a user?

Tags: webhooks, google-fit

User provides his fitness data (stairs, steps) to GoogleFit collected from his Android smartphone.
On the server side I need to know if new data is available for this user.
I need to compute some user specific infomation regarding the number of steps he has done.
Is there any webhook / subscription availabla on GoogleFit API to make this use case ?